# React-Relay older browser support (blank site)

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, relay, react-relay

I have a react-relay graphql app that works perfectly on new browsers, but on safari 5.1.10 (2013) it doesn't work. The site is just white. Same happens with older versions of chrome.

The console gives:
`TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'e.startsWith("client:")')`

I looked through `react-relay/dist/relay.min.js` and saw `isClientID:function(e){return e.startsWith("client:")}`.. it seems thats the failing function.

Has anyone encountered this before? Any ideas on a fix or what could be causing it?

[image: new error]

Comment: add the polyfill? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

Comment: Thanks! It worked, but now we have an issue with supporting the bind function. I tried these babel plugins but they didnt seem to work: `"syntax-function-bind", "transform-function-bind"` @azium any ideas?

Comment: The bind *function* ?? Or do you mean bind syntax `console::log`?

Comment: I just re-read your question.. why on earth are you supporting safari 5 ?!

Comment: haha its unfortunately also happening to i.e 9, 10, & 11. Safari 5 was the whistle blower that led us to discover this. i'm adding the newest error's screenshot to the post @azium

Comment: did you try the polyfill again? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: another thing you might want to look at is an es6 -> es3 compiler

Comment: I added the polyfill to the top of the page before any scripts run (below css), but it didn't help. had the same error  @azium